# Why % CPU doesn't add up to 100?

Tags: cpu-load, process, system-monitor

Why doesn't the "% CPU" in System Monitor add up to 100? (% CPU is the third column on the following screenshot)

[image: cpu time]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. The calculations are per-core. So if you have a dual-core system then the maximum will be 200%.
2. You will not necessarily see all processes which are using your CPU in System Monitor, so the CPU usage might be below 100% for each processor.

Furthermore it is unusual for 100% of any processor to be in use. See the resources tab for the total in use per processor.

Comment: Ah ok, I'm on a dual core that's why! A bit unintuitive though. Thx.

Answer (score 6):

Does your do you have more than one CPU core? Or Hyper-Threading (or the AMD equivalent)?

You can see how many CPUs Ubuntu thinks you have by running this:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "^vendor" | wc -l
```

Ubuntu will count each of these. So if you have 8 CPU's (as I do, quad-core with hyperthreading), you can reach 800% CPU.

Comment: 2 cores. Nice piping btw :)

Answer (score 2):

There is more information regarding this issue at the **askubuntu** link below (a question I asked):

['htop' does not show the correct CPU%, but 'top' does.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15620/htop-does-not-show-the-correct-cpu-but-top-does)